# Валидация на равенство двух значений

Tags: ruby-on-rails, валидация

Я написал следующую валидацию в модели

```
validates :updated_at, inclusion: { in: params.require(:event).permit(:updated_at) }
```

Я хочу получать ошибку, если значение поля формы updated_at не равно значению поля таблицы БД update_at.
И у меня всё не получается получить ту самую updated_at, которая хранится в БД.
На данный код вот такая ошибка:

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:0x0000000767cb20>
```

Как мне получить updated_at из бд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Вам вообще не нужен этот велосипед

Вы пытаетесь сделать [оптимистичную блокировку (optimistic locking, OL)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html). Блокировку вида "конфликтов скорее всего не будет, делай что собираешься, если будет конфликт при записи, тогда будем думать".

В Rails уже есть реализация OL, включается она путём:

1. Добавления `lock_version:integer` в модель.
2. Добавления `lock_version` в форму спрятанным полем.

Чем плох ваш велосипед? Он интересно себя поведёт, если два апдейта случатся в одну и ту же секунду. Оба получат "всё норм, записалось". Но кто-то потеряет свои изменения.

---

#### А что касается исходного вопроса...

**В `params` контроллера из модели лезть категорически нельзя**, это другой слой абстракции. Вы пробиваете дыру в уровне абстракции предметной области (вашей модели объектов реального мира) в уровень абстракции веб-сервиса (который даёт к этой модели доступ посредством HTTP). Теряется возможность использовать ваши модели где-либо кроме вебсервера (например в разовых задачах, и фоновых очередях).

Можно создать у модели виртуальный атрибут, назвать его надо иначе, вроде  `now_updated_at`:

```
attr_accessor :now_updated_at
```

...который прекрасно заполнится штатным образом из параметров, просто в базе храниться не будет. Затем вам нужно валидировать его на равенство. Штатного валидатора на равенство в Rails нет, хотя `inclusion` можно приспособить (многие искоробочные валидаторы принимают вместо констант лямбды/процы и вызывают их в момент валидации):

```
validates :updated_at, inclusion: { in: -> { [now_updated_at] } }, on: :update
```